# Is Abstract Factory just a set of Factory Methods?

Tags: design-patterns

Is Abstract Factory just a set of Factory Methods? Or is there any other difference between these patterns?

Comment: *(reference)* [Abstract Factory](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory) and [Factory Method](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method)

Comment: *(related)* [Design Patterns 15 Years Later: An Interview with Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, and Ralph Johnson](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1404056)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Design Patterns](http://www.amazon.ca/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612), p. 95:

> AbstractFactory classes are often
>   implemented with factory methods, but
>   they can also be implemented using
>   Prototype.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference IMHO is that the abstract factory is **abstract** and that means that it must be subclassed in order to be used. Factory methods cannot be subclassed so you cannot use different implementations of the constructed objects.

If you plan to provide several implementations of the constructed objects, the abstract factory is preferable. Also if you are using unit-testing the abstract factory provides you with better testable code since you can let a mock factory create mock objects for testing.

An abstract factory usually combines multiple factory methods that are coherent.

Comment: I didn't get your point. Factory Method is part of interface or abstract class so it can be subclassed like Abstract Factory

Comment: A factory method is just part of another class (could be a factory class, but could also be any other class). It does not by itself provide any support for subclassing - this is what the astract factory pattern does. The factory method pattern can also be implemented by global functions.

Comment: A factory method is not just a part of another class. "The factory method design pattern handles these problems by defining a separate method for creating the objects, which subclasses can then override to specify the derived type of product that will be created." from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: This is only one (and the most common) implementation. As I said, in some languages a factory method can just be a global function.

Answer (score 0):

The **Abstract Factory** design takes a part of a program and encapsulates it.

The **Factory Method** similarly defines an interface for creating objects.

**Difference :**   `Abstract Factory` is usually implemented as a Singleton which would create a family of objects. It’s usually set while the application loads and not changed afterwards.

On the other hand, `Factory Method`  isn’t usually a thematic group or a Singleton. Instead it is an implementation that allows flexibility in object creation. Thus it doesn’t necessarily create a family of objects

**Similarity** : Both are similar in that they both decouple the creation of an object from its code.

Here's a nice [`pdf`](http://www.buyya.com/254/Patterns/Factory-2pp.pdf) file. Check it out.

Comment: I am pretty sure Abstract Factory also lets subclasses to decide how to instantiate: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

Comment: It is not true that Abstract Factory is usually implemented as Singleton. May be it was so ten years ago, but now it is usually injected like any other dependency.